# .htaccess redirect doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

guys! 
Can anyone help me with Redirect via .htaccess? Why the following code doesn't work?

`Redirect http://website/admin.php http://website/login.php`

Web-server: apache, running on a local PC.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks guys, 301 redirect works well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to put the host in the request part. Just use `/admin.php`:

```
Redirect /admin.php http://example.com/login.php
```

or, to make it permanent:

```
Redirect 301 /admin.php http://example.com/login.php
```

See this for more information: [301 Redirects](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/)

Answer (score 1):

[Try this :](http://www.webconfs.com/htaccess-redirect-generator.php)

```
Redirect 301 /admin.php http://website/login.php
```